# Jquery Chose a certain child by integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I've hidden the **thumb-wrapper**  with javascript. On hover I slide the  thumbs up from their hidden state.  Right now I show all of them.  I'd rather only show the image I want.

Since i have a data data-atribute on the thumbnail link that represents its slide number, I figured the easiest way was to target a child.  Fade in Child 2, or child 3, yata yata yaa.

I thought eq() was the right aproach and had no success.

ie: `$('.orbit-hacked-thumb').eq(2).fadeIn("200");`

ie  `$('.orbit-hacked-thumb:eq(2)').fadeIn("200");`

I've omitted the markup for the selectors, all good there.

***How do I use the integer and select that child?***

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="thumb-wrapper"> 
  <img src="/assets/hpr/carousel/demo-beyonce.png" class="orbit-hacked-thumb"/>
  <img src="http://thetfs.ca/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/black-square.jpg" class="orbit-hacked-thumb" style="height:45px;"/>
  <img src="/assets/hpr/carousel/test.png" class="orbit-hacked-thumb" />
  <img src="/assets/hpr/carousel/test.png" class="orbit-hacked-thumb" />
  <img src="/assets/hpr/carousel/test.png" class="orbit-hacked-thumb" />
  <img src="/assets/hpr/carousel/test.png" class="orbit-hacked-thumb" />
  <img src="/assets/hpr/carousel/test.png" class="orbit-hacked-thumb" />
  <img src="/assets/hpr/carousel/test.png" class="orbit-hacked-thumb" />
  <img src="/assets/hpr/carousel/test.png" class="orbit-hacked-thumb" />
  <img src="/assets/hpr/carousel/test.png" class="orbit-hacked-thumb" />
  <img src="/assets/hpr/carousel/test.png" class="orbit-hacked-thumb" />
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  //hover trigger thumbnails
  $('.orbit-hacked-thumb').hide();
  $('.orbit-bullets li').mouseover(function() {
    child = $(this).attr("data-orbit-slide-number")
    $('.orbit-hacked-thumb').fadeIn("200");
    console.log(child);
  }),
  $('.orbit-bullets li').mouseout(function() {
    $('.orbit-hacked-thumb').hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

your selectors use the `li` element but your HTML contains only `img` elements.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I omitted the markup for the links that are being hovered  over. The selectors are right.